# Archiving C char * stream

Tags: objective-c, serialization, objective-c++, archiving

I'm pretty new to objective-c and I want to be able to archive a `char*` streams (binary data of images). 
The trivial way (for me) to do so is to wrap the `char*` pointer with a objective-c class conforming to `NSCoding protocol`. Is this the right approach or is there a simpler / more convenient way to do so?

Comment: I'd shove it in an NSData.

Comment: Add more code please.

Comment: @bbum Thanks, that what I did. Would you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an NSData to encapsulate the data.   It is NSCoding compliant.